# How map function does sorting in scala

Tags: scala, collections

The following code snippet

```
val keys=List(3,2,1,0)
val unsorted=List(1, 2, 3, 4)
val sorted =keys map unsorted
```

does sorting based on the `keys`.

Normally, map method takes a lambda and apply it to every element in the source. Instead the above code takes a list and does a sorting based on the index.

What is happening in this particular situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List *is* a partial function that goes from its indices to its values. You could look at it like this:

```
scala> List(3,2,1,0) map (i => List(1,2,3,4)(i))
res0: List[Int] = List(4, 3, 2, 1)
```

to verify

```
scala> val f: Int => Int = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
f: Int => Int = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

It does not sorting them, `map` takes a function, lets see:
that statement translates to:

```
keys.map(unsorted.apply)
```

Scala's `List.apply(n: Int)` function return `n`th element of list, in this case `map` makes it:

```
unsorted(3), unsorted(2), unsorted(1), unsorted(4)
```

which is
    `4,3,2,1` which is sorted only by chance in this case.

Test this:

```
scala> val keys = List(3,0,1,2)
keys: List[Int] = List(3, 0, 1, 2)

scala> val unsorted = List(10,20,30,40)
unsorted: List[Int] = List(10, 20, 30, 40)

scala> keys map unsorted
res0: List[Int] = List(40, 10, 20, 30)
```

Comment: It does reordering of list by indices, is that  different from sorting?

Comment: How does passing a list to lambda call apply method?

Comment: I wouldn't call it reordering, if you use `List(0,0,0,0)` as keys here, you will get `List(10,10,10,10)` or for `List(5,5,5,5)` you will get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 5` or if you give `List(0)` it will return `List(10)`, instead of orderin we can say, it returns what element corresponds to given index, and for your other question, if you pass a object to map, scala will use apply by default, this makes creating instances of objects like case classes easy

Comment: @hariharan: `List[T]` is a subclass of `Function[Int, T]`.

Answer (score 1):

In `keys map unsorted` for each value in `keys` we call the `apply` method in list `unsorted` which yields the element at a `key` position.

Swap elements in `keys` and note the outcome, for instance note the last key,

```
val keys=List(2,1,0,3)

val sorted = keys map unsorted
sorted: List[Int] = List(3, 2, 1, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `.map` has not specific relation with sorting.

Your snipet is a specific case that happens to sort. If desugaring, it does as follows.

```
/* keys */List(3,2,1,0).map { i: Int =>
  unsorted.apply(i)
}
```

It applies [unsorted.apply](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@apply(n:Int):A) with each value of `keys` (used as indexes).

Answer (score 0):

It's not sorting at all. It is normal situation: map method takes a lambda and apply it to every element in the source. Just change your `sorted` list and you'll see it.